# How To Access History in React With React-Router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router 6 alpha, and I would like to disable the browser "Back" button by:

- Detecting the back event, and
- On detection, using the history to immediately send the browser forward.

In React-Router 5, this would accomplished with the following code in App.js:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
  history.go(1);
});
```

...while also using the following

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Comp1 extends React.Component { 
    lots of stuff 
}
export default withRouter(Comp1)
```

The problem is... there is no `withRouter`, anymore. There's nothing to wrap the export in, and consequently no access to the history that I can see.  How can I get access to that history, if it's possible at all?  I can still detect the Back button event (an alert box proves that) but I can't see how to move forward by one.

(Ignore for the moment that this implementation obliterates any state held in the component-- I'm just trying to get my arms around this.)

Comment: you have useHistory()

Comment: @robert  in 5.1, maybe.  Not in 6.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there isn't a `withRouter` Higher Order Component to inject a `history` prop, but there is a `useNavigate` hook that essentially replaces the v5 `useHistory` hook.

[useNavigate](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#usenavigate)

> The `useNavigate` hook returns a function that lets you navigate programmatically, for example after a form is submitted.
>
> - Pass the delta you want to go in the history stack. For example, navigate(-1) is equivalent to hitting the back button.

You can force a forward navigation with `navigate(1)`

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

// lots of stuff

...

navigate(1);
```

This, of course, only works in functional components, but it would be a trivial matter to create your own HOC to wrap and pass a `navigate` prop to and serve much the same purpose as `withRouter`.

```
const withNavigate = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <WrappedComponent {...props} navigate={navigate} />;
};
```

Comment: Oh, I see-- I have to detect landing on a page via the back button in the component itself, rather than App.js where the routes are defined?  Meaning, globally, I would have to put that code in every component, if I want to globally disallow the back button?

Comment: @Novak Well, to control the back navigation bluntly you could simply wrap the next component under the `Router` with this, or for more fine-grained control create a more specialized HOC that combines the `navigate` prop with the "popstate" listener and use anywhere you specifically want/need to control back navigation. FYI, there is also a [useBlocker](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#useblocker) hook to block navigation away from a page, which may be similar to what you are looking for.